# How to Save before Exit Java

Tags: java, swing, save, text-editor, exit

I've searched similar threads but I can't seem the find the solution that fits. (I'm new to java)

I have made an texteditor and i need to make the option to save before exit. A possible window that pops up and asks the user if they want to save or not...

The main frame has set this:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

And this is my inner class that handles the event that is generated when the user selects Exit from the file menu.

```
   private class ExitListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try overriding windowClosing event.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725311/how-to-override-windowsclosing-event-in-jframe

Answer (score 2):

So in your frame class you should override the method processWindowEvent.

```
@Override
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
    if(e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING){
        System.out.println("Windows is closing");
    }
    super.processWindowEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: -1, don't override a component when you can use a listener to do the processing. In this case a `WindowListener` was designed for this purpose. The reason you use a listener is because the listener can then potentially be added to any frame, dialog or window and the code becomes more resusable which is always a goal when writing code.